# Show that f'(x) can be approximated by using the following formula.

Tags: derivatives, approximation

Show that $f'(x)$ can be approximated by using the following
formula.
$f'(x) = (4f(x + h) − 3f(x) − f(x − 2h))/6h$
Find the error term and order for the approximation formula.

Confused how to start this question. I know how to prove the Central difference formula for f'' but not this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's $f0(x)$?

Comment: f'(x) sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

We have

$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)$

$+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(c_1)$

and

$f(x-2h)=f(x)-2hf'(x)$

$+2h^2f''(c_2)$

thus

$$6hf'(x)=$$

$$4f(x+h)-3f(x)-f(x-2h)+2h^2(f''c_2)-f''(c_1))$$

the error term is

$$\frac{h}{3}|f''(c_2)-f''(c_1)|\leq\frac{2h}{3}M.$$

where $M=\sup |f''(x)|$.

it's a first order approximation.